# PHP - Extend clock to show 23-24-25 instead of 23-00-01

Tags: php, arrays, datetime, multidimensional-array, clock

Okay, so this is my first question on here, so please show some mercy. I am developing a web application to increase my knowledge in PHP programming, but I have encountered a problem.

My webapp is driven by time. So when for example the clock is 17:00 it shows a piece of information stored in a multidimentional array. And when the clock is 18:30 it shows some other information in the array. The problem is that I have some information that needs to be shown at for example 25:12 without changing the current day.

**So the problem:** 
Can you allow the clock to show the time as 24:00-25:00-26:00 instead of 00:00-01:00-02:00 and while still be on the same day? Say for example the day will change from Monday to Tuesday after the clock is 26:00?

This is an example of the multidimensional array. It works fine all the way up to 23:59, but the clock is of course only going up to 00:00 and the day is of course changing. So can you "extend" the day in PHP?

**Example:**

```
//This is one of the arrays I´ve got. This one only works on Monday-Friday. 
//It´s called "H103.php
$tur = array
(
array("RYEV", "6:26", "Møt", 1),
array("RYEV", "6:36", "Uttak", 1),
array("RYE2", "6:39+", "N", 1),
array("FRS2", "7:29", "D", 1),
array("FRS1", "7:43", "N", 1),
array("BKR1", "8:47+", "N", 1),
array("FRS2", "9:44", "D", 1),
array("FRS1", "9:58", "N", 1),
array("BKR1", "11:02+", "N", 1),
array("FRS2", "11:59", "D", 1),
array("FRS1", "12:13", "N", 1),
array("BKR1", "13:17+", "N", 1),
array("FRS1", "14:14", "D", 1),
array("FRS1", "14:28", "N", 1),
array("BKR1", "15:32+", "N", 1),
array("FRS2", "16:29", "D", 1),
array("FRS1", "16:43", "N", 1),
array("BKR1", "17:47+", "N", 1),
array("FRS2", "18:44", "D", 1),
array("FRS1", "18:58", "N", 1),
array("HFY2", "20:00+", "N", 1),
array("FRS2", "20:44", "D", 1),
array("FRS1", "20:58", "N", 1),
array("HFY2", "22:00+", "N", 1),
array("FRS2", "22:44", "D", 1),
array("FRS1", "22:58", "N", 1),
array("HFY2", "24:00+", "N", 1),
array("FRS2", "24:47", "D", 1),
array("MAJ3", "25:15", "D", 1),
array("AVL2", "25:35", "D", 1),
array("SPO6", "25:38", "Inn", 1),
);

//Define time into variable and counts array in total.
$klokkeT = date("H:i");
$antT = count($tur);
$u = 0;

//Finding out which line from the array to take based on time, 
//and the storing it in a variable to show it on the website. 

if ($_SESSION["kjoreLinje"] == 1 && $_SESSION["retning"] == "O"){
for ($m = 0; $m < $antT; $m++) {
   $u++;
    if ($u < $antT) {
        if ($klokkeT >= $tur[$m][1] AND $klokkeT <= $tur[$u][1]) {
            $turF1 = $tur[$m][0]; $turF2 = $tur[$m][1]; $turF3 = $tur[$m][2];
            $turF4 = $tur[$m][3]; $turN1 = $tur[$u][0]; $turN2 = $tur[$u][1];
            $turN3 = $tur[$u][2]; $turN4 = $tur[$u][3];
        } } }

//System choosing which file to take based on what day it is
$weekdays =  array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday");

//weekdays
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
 if ($_SESSION["day"] == $weekdays[$i]) {
        if ($_SESSION["togNr"] == 103) {
        include_once 'Kjoretavler/Hverdag/Linje1/H103.php'; }
//Saturday
if ($_SESSION["dag"] == "Saturday") {
        if ($_SESSION["togNr"] == 103) {
        include_once 'Kjoretavler/Lordag/Linje1/L103.php'; }
//Sunday
if ($_SESSION["dag"] == "Sunday") {
        if ($_SESSION["togNr"] == 103) {
        include_once 'Kjoretavler/Sondag/Linje1/S103.php'; }
```

Comment: Why do you have to stick to a certain day? Is time difference not sufficient? You could parse 24:00+ hours separately to fix that.

Comment: You should also show us some php code ...

Comment: Let me try to explain. I have a lot of PHP-files with data stored in multidimensional arrays. Some files is only active on for example Monday, while some other files are only active on Saturday. That´s why I have to "extend" the day to for example Monday - 26:32, because the different timestamps stored in the multidimentional array goes all the way up to 26:30. 

Changing only the time will not work for my instance since file.php only is active on monday and file2.php is only active on saturday (just a example).

Comment: So how do you compare the day of week? You have only talked about time so far. Is it by date? Is it by "monday". Or how?? Is the time compared at the same time?

Comment: As I said in my question: 
"Can you allow the clock to show the time as 24:00-25:00-26:00 instead of 00:00-01:00-02:00 and while still be on the same day? Say for example the day will change from Monday to Tuesday after the clock is 26:00?"

So all I need is PHP to believe that for example monday starts on 02:00 instead of 00:00, and the same with all the other 6 days a week, while showing the clock as 24-25-26 while jumping back to 03 (and going all the way up from 03-26 again) when it comes to 27.

Comment: Yes, But where do you compare the day of week, and how?

Comment: You said some files are only active on mondays, but how do you know if it is monday. Supply us with that code

Comment: @MarcusHovet I updated the code below. Now you have one $day and one $time.

Comment: Well, @Andreas. As said, this is my first question on here so sorry for being unclear and that my explaining suck. I´ve edited my first post with code to hopefully answer your question. 

$_SESSION["dag"] are being defined when the user enters the website and always stores the current day

Comment: @Marcus forget that part about badly explaining, it's really a part which could, and should, have been excluded from that comment. Thanks for an overall good and interesting first question, I hope you'll hang along and find what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got @Andreas answer to work with some modifying. It seems altough that he has removed his answer, so I can´t give him the credit he deserves. Thanks again, and sorry for the bad explaining. I´ve learned a lot already. EDIT: The code that worked for me.

```
  if (date("G") <= 3) {
    $day = Date("l", strtotime("yesterday"));
    $time = 24 + intval(date("G")) . date(":i");
} else {
    $day = date("l");
    $time = date("G:i");
}
echo $day . " \n";
echo $time;
```

Comment: If you can, please explain, with code, how you actually solved this. While self answers are acceptable, and can even be marked as accepted (see the green checkmark beside your answer), it is preferable that they contain an answer, should anyone else have your problem in the future

Comment: Done! :) Thanks a lot

Comment: How does 9+ hours equal 24? Is the server in a different country as the users? That won't work. When you shift day from monday to tuesday, the server will be in the incorrect day and "yesterday" will not be yesterday. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: I haven't fully tested it yet, but I will edit it if it doesn't work. You are most likely correct, but when I tried to run your code with the time set to "1:24" (as an example) it just gave me "Tuesday 42:13" when I was supposed to get "Tuesday 25:24".

Comment: Probably because of timezones problems. Either you solve it like above mentioned, or edit php.ini http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php/setting-the-timezone-for-php-in-the-phpini-file . But "just dealing with it" as you do in your code will give you headache like you have never felt before.

Comment: Also. You use "H" format in your array but "G" format of date in your code. Again headache. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php . I didn't know what format you used so that could be the issue also.

Comment: That's true. Thanks for pointing that out. Hopefully I'll get it to work later on.

Comment: @Andreas your code worked perfectly. It was just my own fault. Thanks a lot! :) Edited in the correct code now.